# namespace of .NET ComboBoxItem

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox

where is the `ComboBoxItem` class in the .NET namespace of Visual Studio 2012?
MSDN says it should be in `Windows.Controls` but there is no such namespace or any entry of it in the references list.
It's also not present in `Windows.Forms`.
I've only encountered a `ListViewItem` class, but that messes up the label with tags and brackets.

Comment: From [MSDN (link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx):  Namespace:  System.Windows.Forms, 
Assembly:  System.Windows.Forms (in System.Windows.Forms.dll)

Comment: The one in `Windows.Controls` is for WPF applications. It's declared in the `PresentationFramework` assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ComboBoxItem` can only be found if you create a **WPF project**, because namespace `System.Windows.Controls` is included in `PresentationFramework` assembly.
If you're creating a **WinForms project**, you cannot find `ComboBoxItem` class!
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are probably programming in WinForms or in ASP.NET.

In WinForms you don't have a ComboBoxItem. You simply [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.add.aspx) objects to the [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx) and the ComboBox uses their `ToString()` method to show them.

In ASP.NET you don't even have a ComboBox :-) You have a [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx) that uses [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx)

Comment: Here's how to twiddle them: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d041df37-faae-4565-9beb-726470a65542/how-to-change-color-of-content-of-combo-box-in-vbnet